# Try to use SignalR in my cshtml to update schedule time table in background with out refresh browser ,but got an error in Hub class

Tags: signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

every thing is fine when i try to connect to signalR and gave me a token and Connection is stablished
but when client call the hub class  and i i want to invoke my updated json data to client got error and never found what happend .

my project is an asp.net core web app razor page with .net 7
i have a TimeTable.cshtml that shows  scheduleTime Table and must update every 1 minute at least so , i connect to signalR via javascript

here is my code in hub class

```
using Dapper;
using GameFest.Model;
using GameFest.Web.Data;
using GameFest.Web.Helpers;
using GameFest.Web.Services.Contracts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

namespace GameFest.Web.Areas.Portal.Services
{
    [Authorize]`your text`
    public class BtlNetHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
       
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private Timer _timer;

        public BtlNetHub(ApplicationDbContext db, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _db = db;
            _config = config;

            // set up the timer
            _timer = new Timer();
            _timer.Interval = IntervalInMilliseconds;
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
           
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }

        private const int IntervalInMilliseconds = 60000;

        // define method as an endpoint
        [HubMethodName("updateSchedule")]
        public async Task UpdateSchedule()
        {
            using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("GameFestConnection"));
            using var data = await connection.QueryMultipleAsync("p_GameFest_Events_AllSchedule", new { },
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            ScheduleTimeTableDto Schedule = new ScheduleTimeTableDto();
            try
            {
                var holdings = (await data.ReadAsync<ScheduleHoldingDto>()).ToList();

                if (holdings == null)
                {
                    // handle null value
                    Console.WriteLine("holdings is null");
                }
                else
                {
                    List<EventHoldingDto> hl = new List<EventHoldingDto>();
                    foreach (var evnt in holdings)
                    {
                        hl.Add(new EventHoldingDto
                        {
                            HoldingCode = evnt.HoldingCode,
                            EventID = evnt.EventID,
                            StartDate = DateTimeConverter.ConvertToDateTime(evnt.StartDate),
                            Status = evnt.Status,
                            OrgFirstName = evnt.OrgFirstName,
                            EventTitle = evnt.EventTitle,
                            ShortDesc = evnt.ShortDesc,
                            StatusTitle = StatusComponents.ShowStatusTitle(evnt.Status, "holding"),
                            EndDate = DateTimeConverter.ConvertToDateTime(evnt.EndDate),
                            OrgImageUrl = evnt.OrgImageUrl,
                            OrgLastName = evnt.OrgLastName,
                            ParticipantQty = evnt.ParticipantQty,
                            OrganizerID = evnt.OrganizerID,
                            PlayerQty = evnt.ParticipantQty - evnt.PlayerQty
                        });
                    }

                    Schedule.Holdings = hl;
                }

                if (Schedule != null)
                {                    
                    await Clients.All.SendAsync("updateSchedule", Schedule);
                }
                else
                {
                    await Clients.All.SendAsync("showErrorMessage", "خطا در بروزرسانی برنامه‌زمانی رخ داده است.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("showErrorMessage", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private async Task CallUpdateSchedule()
        {
            using (var hub = new BtlNetHub(_db, _config))
            {
                if (hub != null && _timer.Enabled)
                {
                    await hub.UpdateSchedule();
                }
            }
        }

        private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // update the schedule on the client
                _ = CallUpdateSchedule();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
await Clients.All.SendAsync("updateSchedule", Schedule);
```

this code got error null exception  and i am sure that Schedule is not null and something wrong with Clinets .
this function call every less than 60 second  and couldn't send data to client(My cshtml page via javascript)
please give me someway to figure it out  thanks

Comment: Hi Moji, please set breakpoint in your backend and add `debugger` at `updateSchedule` method in your javascript. I want to confirm  `Schedule` is null or not. And the next action is enable client-side and server-side logging, to check more detail.

Comment: If you could provide minimal sample project for us, I am willing to help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: i already set break point   in backend and Schedule is not null for sure.
something wrong with  Clients.Caller.SendAsync  method 
because when i  get exception  and call  await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("showErrorMessage", ex.Message); to get error message 
still give me that error. it means  it's not about schedule object .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, the client object was equal to null and had nothing to do with the data schedule. That's why I looked for why this happens.
As a result, I realized that I should use the IHubContext interface for clients that are context

```
 public BtlNetHub(ApplicationDbContext db, IConfiguration config,IHubContext<BtlNetHub> hubContext)
    {
        _db = db;
        _config = config;
       _hubContext = hubContext;

        // set up the timer
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = IntervalInMilliseconds;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
       
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }

    private const int IntervalInMilliseconds = 60000;

    // define method as an endpoint
    [HubMethodName("updateSchedule")]
    public async Task UpdateSchedule()
    {
        using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("GameFestConnection"));
        using var data = await connection.QueryMultipleAsync("p_GameFest_Events_AllSchedule", new { },
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        ScheduleTimeTableDto Schedule = new ScheduleTimeTableDto();
        try
        {
            var holdings = (await data.ReadAsync<ScheduleHoldingDto>()).ToList();

            if (holdings == null)
            {
                // handle null value
                Console.WriteLine("holdings is null");
            }
            else
            {
                List<EventHoldingDto> hl = new List<EventHoldingDto>();
                foreach (var evnt in holdings)
                {
                    hl.Add(new EventHoldingDto
                    {
                        HoldingCode = evnt.HoldingCode,
                        EventID = evnt.EventID,
                        StartDate = DateTimeConverter.ConvertToDateTime(evnt.StartDate),
                        Status = evnt.Status,
                        OrgFirstName = evnt.OrgFirstName,
                        EventTitle = evnt.EventTitle,
                        ShortDesc = evnt.ShortDesc,
                        StatusTitle = StatusComponents.ShowStatusTitle(evnt.Status, "holding"),
                        EndDate = DateTimeConverter.ConvertToDateTime(evnt.EndDate),
                        OrgImageUrl = evnt.OrgImageUrl,
                        OrgLastName = evnt.OrgLastName,
                        ParticipantQty = evnt.ParticipantQty,
                        OrganizerID = evnt.OrganizerID,
                        PlayerQty = evnt.ParticipantQty - evnt.PlayerQty
                    });
                }

                Schedule.Holdings = hl;
            }

            if (Schedule != null)
            {                    
                await  _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("updateSchedule", Schedule);
            }
            else
            {
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("showErrorMessage", "Error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            await  _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("showErrorMessage", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```